# D3js working with unknown: headers/number of columns/number of rows

Tags: arrays, csv, d3.js

I am trying to work with CSV files but with **unknown header** names. How can I refer to each column without knowing the name of the header? Also the number of columns and rows is unknown. What do you think would be the best approach for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could get an array of the header names by calling `d3.keys()` on the first row of the data returned from `d3.csv`:

```
d3.csv('path/to/your/file.csv', function(error, data) {
  var headers = d3.keys(data[0]);
})
```

Then, depending on what you're trying to do, you could iterate over this array and use each of the header names in turn. For example:

```
d3.csv('path/to/your/file.csv', function(error, data) {
  var headers = d3.keys(data[0]);
  for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
    doSomething(headers[i]);
  }
})
```

As far as the number of rows, you can find that out simply by getting the `length` property of the returned data.

```
d3.csv('path/to/your/file.csv', function(error, data) {
  var numRows = data.length;
})
```

---

Jeff K asked if there is a way to guarantee that the order of the keys parsed from the header is the same as was defined in the original file. This is possible, but you need to use the lower-level d3 methods for text parsing.

You can fetch the raw text of the file using `d3.text` and then parse the rows individually using `d3.csv.parseRows`. Here is an example:

```
d3.text('path/to/your/file.csv')
  .get(function(error, rows) {
    var parsedRows = d3.csv.parseRows(rows);
    var headers = parsedRows[0];
  })
```

The `d3.csv.parseRows` function creates a two-dimensional Array; an Array of rows, each row being an Array of its values:

```
[
  [ 'Header1', 'Header2', 'Header3' ],
  [ 329847, 21384, 72912 ],
  [ 232323, 12338, 3218 ],
  ... etc ...
]
```

By taking the first element in the `parsedRows` array, you can get back the array of all header values in the order they were defined.

**Note:** For d3v4 use `d3.csvParseRows` instead of `d3.csv.parseRows`

Comment: OK I ll try that and see how that works out. Thank you

Comment: Well I tried that method. Got the headers in the array but how do I use that to access the differnt columns. Up till now I was using d.columnName but d.headers[0] doesnt seem to be working. Lets say for example that I have 4 columns and I want to know the largest value in my first column. How will I use the d3.max() function with that?

Comment: If you define your variable `headers` the way I have above, you can find the max value in the first column like this: `d3.max(data, function(d) {return d[headers[0]];})` You need to use bracket notation rather than dot notation because `headers` is a variable rather than the key you are trying to retrieve.

Comment: Thanks a lot that was great help!

Comment: @jshanley I don't think d3.keys can guarantee order for the keys. Is there a way to know exactly which key is the first, second, third, etc in the CSV header?

Comment: @jshanley thanks, nice example. To keep this working nicely with the charts I already had I did the following: `var parsedRows = d3.csv.parseRows(rows); var headers = parsedRows[0]; var data = d3.csv.parse(rows);`